# ¿Cómo ver parámetros requeridos del procedimiento almacenado sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

estoy trayendo información de un procedimiento "x" donde puedo ver sus características, pero necesito que la consulta me devuelva si el parámetro es requerido y cuando no es requerido a nivel de sql  hasta el momento tengo esto, espero cualquier ayuda gracias.

```
SELECT 
SCHEMA_NAME(SCHEMA_ID) AS [Schema],
SO.name AS [ObjectName],
P.parameter_id AS [ParameterID],
P.name AS [ParameterName],
TYPE_NAME(P.user_type_id) AS [ParameterDataType],
P.max_length AS [ParameterMaxBytes],
P.is_output AS [IsOutPutParameter]
FROM sys.objects AS SO  
INNER JOIN sys.parameters AS P ON SO.OBJECT_ID = P.OBJECT_ID
where SO.name='BG_SP_CAS_DetalleEvento'
ORDER BY [Schema], SO.name, P.parameter_id
GO
```

resultado hasta el momento sin éxito

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Según la documentación, no se puede a menos de que revises el código directamente. La columna que podría servir, solo funciona para objetos CLR.

Comment: alguna otra opción para este problema  ?